# Не могу понять,как добавить не типизированный итератор и цикл foreach

Tags: java

Я пытаюсь добавить
1)Не типизированный итератор,  который делает список актеров , которые играли уже в одном фильме с указанным актером
2)Типизированный цикл foreach ,который вычисляет фильм с наибольшим количеством участников
Idk what to do.Hope you will help me

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Film film1 = new Film("Harry Potter");
        Film film2 = new Film("Split");
        Film film3 = new Film("Victor Frankenstein");
        Film film4 = new Film("Tenet");
        Film film5 = new Film("Black Panther");
        Film film6 = new Film("Piraty Caribskogo morya");



        Actor actor1 = new Actor("Daniel Redcliff");
        Actor actor2 = new Actor("Emma Watson");
        Actor actor3 = new Actor("James McAvoy");
        Actor actor4 = new Actor("Chedwick Bouzman");
        Actor actor5 = new Actor("Jhony D.");

        Database.addFilm(film1);
        Database.addFilm(film2);
        Database.addFilm(film3);
        Database.addFilm(film4);
        Database.addFilm(film5);
        Database.addFilm(film6);
        Database.addActor(actor1);
        Database.addActor(actor2);
        Database.addActor(actor3);
        Database.addActor(actor4);
        Database.addActor(actor5);

        film1.addActor(actor1);
        film1.addActor(actor2);
        film2.addActor(actor3);
        film3.addActor(actor1);
        film3.addActor(actor3);
        film4.addActor(actor4);
        film5.addActor(actor2);
        film6.addActor(actor4);
        actor1.addFilm(film1);
        actor1.addFilm(film3);
        actor2.addFilm(film1);
        actor3.addFilm(film2);
        actor3.addFilm(film3);
        actor4.addFilm(film4);
        actor4.addFilm(film5);
        actor3.addFilm(film6);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\n");
    

    


    

    }
```

```
    private static List<Actor> notFilmed() {
        List<Actor> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterator<Actor> actorIterator = Database.getActors().iterator();
        while (actorIterator.hasNext()) {
            Actor actor = actorIterator.next();
            Iterator<Film> filmIterator = Database.getFilms().iterator();

            boolean present = false;
            while (filmIterator.hasNext()) {
                Film film = filmIterator.next();
                if (film.getActors().contains(actor)) {
                    present = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!present) {
                resultList.add(actor);
            }
        }

        return resultList;

    }



}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Actor {
 private String name;
 private List<Film> films = new ArrayList();
 public Actor(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public void addFilm(Film film) {
  this.films.add(film);
 }
 public List<Film> getFilms(){
  return this.films;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Actor{" +
          "name='" + name + '\'' +
          ", films=" + films +
          '}';
 }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Database {
    private static List<Film> allfilms = new ArrayList();
    public static void addFilm(Film film) {
        allfilms.add(film);
    }

    private static List<Actor> allactors = new ArrayList();
    public static void addActor(Actor actor) {
        allactors.add(actor);
    }

    public static List<Actor> getActors(){
        return allactors;
    }
    public static List<Film> getFilms(){
        return allfilms;
    }

    public Database() {
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Film {
    private String name;
    private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList();
    public Film(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addActor(Actor actor) {
        this.actors.add(actor);
    }
    public List<Actor> getActors(){
        return this.actors;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    **public Film(String name, List<Actor> actors) {
        this.name = name;**
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Film{" +



                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

that`s all

Comment: Куда пытаетесь добавить? Что не получается? В чем помочь?

Comment: мне нужно добавить не типизированный итератор в класс Main(извиняюсь за неточность формулировки,только учусь )

Comment: Попробую догадаться... Вы его хотите использовать или свой написать? Если использовать, то в каком методе? Что хотите перебирвть этим итератором? И воообще - почему НЕтипизированный?

Comment: Надо использовать в методе main,перебрать этим итератором актеров,которые играли в одном фильме с указанным актером(мы должны его выбрать).